# React-query with NextJs routing

Tags: next.js, react-query

I have a page with few queries and it's all working until I update the URL params and then react-query stops working and also disappear from dev-tools.

When I click on a row it triggers the handleRowClick function which update the URL with params, and then react query stops working.

1.[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwZIL.png)

2.Clicking on a row ( Update URL params ) [Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlYhV.png)

```
const Volumes: NextPage = () => {
const apiRef = useGridApiRef()

const [volumes, setVolumes] = useState<IDataset[] | undefined>(undefined)
const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false)
const [rightWingData, setRightWingData] = useState<IDataset | undefined>(undefined)
const [searchValue, setSearch] = useState('')
const [volumeId, setVolumeId] = useState('')

const { isLoading, data } = useVolumeData()
const { isLoading: searchIsLoading, data: searchData } = useSearchVolumes(searchValue)
const { isLoading: volumeByIdLoading, data: volumeByIdData } = useVolumeDataById(volumeId)

const router = useRouter()

useEffect(() => {
    if(router.isReady && router.query?.id && !rightWingData){
        const volumeId = router.query.id.toString()
        setVolumeId(volumeId)
    }

    if (!isLoading && data && !searchData) {
        setVolumes(data.data.result)
    }
    else if (!searchIsLoading) {
        setVolumes(searchData)
    }

    if(!volumeByIdLoading && volumeByIdData){
        showVolumeData(volumeByIdData)
    }
}, [data, isLoading, searchIsLoading, searchData, isOpen, rightWingData, volumeByIdLoading, volumeByIdData])


const handleRowClick = (rowData: IRowData) => {
    showVolumeData(rowData.row)
    Router.push({
        pathname: '/volumes',
        query: { id: rowData.row.id},
    })
}

const showVolumeData = (volumeData: IDataset) => {
    apiRef.current.updateColumns(thinColumns)
    setRightWingData(volumeData)
    setOpen(true)
    setVolumeId('')
}

const closeRightWing = () => {
    setOpen(false)
    Router.push('/volumes')
    apiRef.current.updateColumns(columns)
}

if (isLoading || !volumes) return <h1>Is Loading...</h1>

return (
    <div className={`volumes ${isOpen ? "open" : "close"}`}>
        <div className="volumes-table">
            <InfTable setSearch={setSearch} searchValue={searchValue} apiRef={apiRef}
                rows={volumes} columns={columns} initialState={initialState} onRowClick={handleRowClick} />
        </div>
        {rightWingData &&
            <div className="right-wing-wrapper" >
                <VolumeRightWing volume={rightWingData} onClose={closeRightWing} />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
)
```

}

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
const queryClient = new QueryClient()

return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
            <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} position="bottom-right" />
        </Layout>
    </QueryClientProvider>
)
```

}

Comment: you need to show us some code please, otherwise, it is impossible to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you show where / how the queryClient is created? I have a hunch that an unstable client could be the cause.

Comment: @TkDodo - I added the code snippet for the queryClient

Comment: @TkDodo - The problem was that the queryClient was created inside the component every-time it rerenders, so I moved it outside the component.
However I wonder why every time the URL changes it rerenders the entire App.
Is there a way to prevent it in next.js?

Answer (score 4):

as shown in the code, you are re-creating a `new QueryClient` inside the `App` component:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient()
```

which means that every time the App re-renders, you throw away the Query Cache (which is stored inside the client).

This is likely what happens when you change the route params. If you cannot create the client *outside* of `MyApp` (e.g. because you are using server-side rendering), it is advised to create a *stable* client:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const [queryClient] = React.useState(() => new QueryClient())
```

this is also shown in [the SSR docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/ssr).

Comment: I created the client outside of the App component and it works.
The problem was that when the URL changes next.js rerenders the App component.

Comment: @LiorZelitchenok Thanks, extracting create of QueryClient instance fixed this.